# Firebase hosted website shows welcome page not the actual website

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am trying to host React website using firebase. I have used firebase for backend. I have already deployed a website using firebase it worked fine before. Only this time the deployed url keeps showing the welcome page.
I have tried deleting firebase files and tried `firebase init` multiple times still facing the same issue . I tried opening the file in incognito mode but it shows the same thing.

Hosted url:
https://recipe-661e9.web.app/

I started with `npm install -g firebase-tools` and it worked fine

Then I did `firebase login` and it showed I'm logged in.

Then `firebase init`

After `firebase init` these were the choices I made

```
Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this director
y? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your cho
ices. Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optional
ly) set up GitHub Action deploys

Please select an option: Use an existing project
? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: recipe-661e9 (Recipe)

 What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
✔  Wrote build/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
```

After this I ran `npm run build`
followed by `firebase deploy --only hosting`

I have googled multiple times but finding no solution.
I tried deleting firebase.json , .firebaserc file and its folder and running these commands again but same thing.
I have tried deleting build folder still no improvement

Comment: Your instructions don't say anything about changing the content that you want to deploy from the default you're given.  As far as I can tell, you are deploying the default generated build/index.html, which contains the welcome page you're seeing.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have deleted build and tried again still same errors. Any possible suggestions please?

Comment: You are deploying the `build` directory. What's in that directory? Did you build the React project into that directory? If not, then the build directory contains the default page you're seeing.

Comment: @AnisAbboud I think you're right .how am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: @AnisAbboud I tried adding the react project in the build directory using "nom run build". What else I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy the public directory instead of build